# Commit NSTextField changes before saving

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an `NSDocument` app and I would like to have a `NSTextField` to commit the current changes to the model every time the user save (through cmd+s for example).

I don't use binding and at the moment the changes are pushed to the model in the `-controlTextDidEndEditing:` method. Calling the `[window makeFirstResponder:nil]` does push the changes to the model but also causes the control to lose focus which is not really a reasonable behaviour.

Googling around I have seen that several people suggested to use the `-commitEditing` method but it only applies to bindings, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call your already defined `controlTextDidEndEditing:` from your `save` action:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    [self controlTextDidEndEditing: ...]
}
```

to trigger the same code you already wrote!